# Why is the convergence point of $ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} $ negative?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to evaluate $\frac1{2^1} - \frac1{2^2} + \frac1{2^3} - \frac1{2^4} + \cdots$

I re-wrote the sum using sigma notation as:
$$ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left( \frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \right) \quad (1) $$

Hence,

$$ (1) =  \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{2^{n+1} - 2^n }{2^n2^{n+1}} = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{2^n(2-1) }{2^n2^{n+1}} = - \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }  \frac1{2^{n+1}}  = - \sum _{n=2}^{\infty }  \frac1{2^{n}} = -\left( \sum _{n=0}^{\infty }  \left(\frac12\right)^n -1-\frac12\right) = -2+\frac32 =-\frac12 $$

Therefore,

$$ \boxed{\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} =-\frac12} $$

---

I can't spot any algebraic mistakes, thus I assume the sum is correct. But I don't understand the result. How can a real valued sum converge to a negative number?

Comment: $2-1=1$ not $-1$ in first line.

Comment: When you write $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$ do you actually mean
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)?$$

Comment: @AnginaSeng Yes, I'll edit, thanks

Comment: Just a little thing : once rewrote, you should have the sum for $n \geq 1$ of the  $2^{-2n+1}-2^{-2n } $ to get $2^{-1}-2^{-2}+2 {-3}-2^{-4} +... $ .

Comment: @Veriun The important thing is that it **isn't** $\frac12-\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{2^3}-\frac1{2^4}+\cdots$.

Comment: You have to use n = 2k and then k from 0 to $\infty$ or something because what you are trying to evaluate is not the same.

Comment: Thank you all. Silly mistakes on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon your original sum is
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}-\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\right).$$
Of course, this is a GP.

Comment: Is there a reason you wrote  $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}-\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\right).$$ instead of
$$ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left( \frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \right) $$
? Aren't these the same sums?

Comment: @Veriun Please read the first line of your question.

Answer (score 1):

In the first step

$$(1) =  \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{2^{n+1} - 2^n }{2^n2^{n+1}} = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{2^n(2-1) }{2^n2^{n+1}} =  \color{red}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }  \frac1{2^{n+1}}  = \ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

You wrote, $\frac{1}{2^1} - \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} - \frac{1}{2^4} + \cdots = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left( \frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \right) $ ,

This is not correct,

$\frac{1}{2^1} - \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} - \frac1{2^4} + \cdots = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{2^n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2n-1}} - 
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2n}} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^2}} - \frac{1}{2^2} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^2}} = \frac{2}{3} - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{3} $ .

Answer (score 0):

The series you are trying to evaluate is

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\left(\frac12\right)^n=\frac12\frac1{1+\dfrac12}=\frac13.$$